# How to remove spaces in front as well as the end of the string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, string

How to strip spaces in front as well as the end of the string.

e.g. "  Hello" or "Hello  " would just strip like this "Hello"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's called `String#strip` :)

```
'Hello  '.strip # => "Hello"
'   Hello'.strip # => "Hello"
```